# Ogre3D 1.9, cmake, XCode, don't know what to put inside FREETYPE_FT2BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, ogre3d, cmake-gui

I'm trying to build from source, I installed the dependencies through homebrew.

In the missing FREETYPE_FT2BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR var, i put /usr/local/include/freetype2

I'm using makefiles. At 83%, it compiles ogre overlay, and I got

```
ld: framework not found FREETYPE
```

There are no official precompiled 1.9 binaries, there is 1.8 but no 1.8.1.

I really need to make this work on mac so I can continue using ogre. It seems building from source is the best solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `FREETYPE_FT2BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR`, you have to add `FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR`, `FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DBG` and `FREETYPE_LIBRARY_REL` vars as well.

Like this:

```
//Path to a file.
FREETYPE_FT2BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.3_1/include/freetype2

//Path to a file.
FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/local/include/freetype2

//Path to a library.
FREETYPE_LIBRARY_DBG:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib

//Path to a library.
FREETYPE_LIBRARY_REL:FILEPATH=/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib
```

Good luck!